# Received a Unable to get value of the property 'Execute': object is null or undefined with Jscript - Crm2011 Onchange Event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I created 3 whole number fields in a CRM form:  var1  var2  and result

I need  var 2 to be subtracted from var1  and display the result, in the result field

Added the Jscript code to the form event,  and added an onchange event to the var1 and var2 field.

I'm receiving the error:
Unable to get value of the property 'Execute': object is null or undefined

Here's my JScript:

```
function calculates( )
{

    var val1 = Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get(safe_val1).getValue();
    var val2 = Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get(safe_val2).getValue();

    if(val1=null) return;
    if(val2=null) return;

    var result = val1 - val2;

    Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get(safe_result).setValue(result);
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers my question!

Comment: 1. Critical typo in conditionals. You're assigning `null`, not comparing. 2. In JS, you need to compare using three equality signs, sometimes. 3. I'm not sure if you got the right values in the variables referring to the field names.

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax of  `Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get` requires you to pass the name of a field.

e.g. suppose I am on the `Contact` form and I want to grab the `firstname` field, I would use

```
 Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('firstname');
```

In your example above you are passing in to `variables` called `safe_val1` and `safe_val2`. There is no suggestion these are initialised anywhere, so that means are you are passing `null` which will make CRM cry.

You need to look at the names of the fields you want to pass in and use them instead.

edit: just noticed you are missing the `data` object

edit2: Alternatively you can use the shorthand/shortcut method

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_fieldname');
```

Comment: I tried that and just tried that again,  but am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Where? I would suggest updating your question with the full error.

Comment: Here the first part of the error that would be sent to MS.
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
   <Message>Unable to get value of the property 'Execute': object is null or undefined</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>

Comment: Can you copy/paste that entire error into your question detail?

Comment: Is there a certain part of the error you are looking for.  Reason is, there is a limit to how much I can be posted in the comment.

Comment: <URL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=10046&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1361454752584</URL>
   <PageURL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=10046&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1361454752584</PageURL>
   <Function></Function><CallStack></CallStack></ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation><BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC EA 2)</BrowserUserAgent>
<ClientName>Web</ClientName>

Comment: Can you not edit your actual question (the bit you wrote originally, right at the top?) and post the whole lot in there?

Comment: I am very new to using JScrip and CRM.  The names of my fields are safe_val1 and safe_val2.   I named them on the form as val1 and val2 and in the SQL DB, their names are  safe_val1 and safe_val2

Comment: Would I put at the top of the code  Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get('safe_val1');

Comment: Note my last update: you need to use Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('safe_val1')

Comment: and also safe_val2 etc.     then add the rest of my code starting with var val1 =    etc...

Comment: glosrob,  I'm going to have to pick up a jScript book and get the basics down.   I'll come back to this after I learn more.  I'm just starting and need to look at samples.   Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: I looked at a tutorial and learned a little.  With it's help and yours I got the following working:

Comment: function calculates( )
{

var val1Value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('safe_val1').getValue();
var val2Value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('safe_val2').getValue();

var resultValue = val1Value - val2Value;


Xrm.Page.getAttribute('safe_result').setValue(resultValue);

}

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a whack, but I'm not in front of the computer so it's just a general suggestion (that **might** resolve your issue).

There are some issues with the code. I'd rewrite it as follows and get back to tell what's happening then.

```
function calculate() {
  // Make sure that you refer the right fields.
  var val1 = Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get("var1").getValue();
  var val2 = Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get("var2").getValue();

  // Yes! Triple equality sign. I'm not BS'ing. I'm JS'ing.
  if(val1 === null || val2 === null) return;

  // Make sure that the computation's been carried out properly.
  var result = val1 - val2;
  alert(result);

  Xrm.Page.entity.attributes.get(safe_result).setValue(result);
}
```

If you want to tear out your eyes from the sockets watching the ugly and weird

```
if(val1 === null || val2 === null) return;
```

you might want to exchange it for

```
if(!val1 || !val2) return;
```

which is also ugly and weird but less. And if this fails, comment everything out and do **exactly** the following. Just to make sure that we eliminate other issues you might have.

```
function calculate(){
  alert("Konrad Viltersten is godlike but humble.");
}
```

If it works, you go shotgun and add **one line** at a time to see when the weird stuff starts happening. (JS - where the joy of programming goes to die.)